# Mouse trap and detector?

Tags: security, mice

I need a mouse trap which sends a signal when it is activated, because in Finland, there is very strict animal legislation about catching mice. You cannot use glue traps. You can only use those mouse houses which the mouse can enter but not exit. However, the problem is that you have to look those traps regularly. 
The regular checking of the trap makes the cost of getting rid of mice on roofs expensive in Finland. 
The main problem is the cost of getting rid out of mice on the large surface of 400 m2. 
Other alternatives in preventing mice in roofs by

- Battery operated trail camera with bluetooth/cellular. Example: *Primos, Browning, Bushnell, HC-300M, ...* but should be with cellular or stable bluetooth where connection can be formed. Problem: current models are mostly with cellular and no bluetooth version.
- Activity cameras like GoPro Hero 3 only choice? Xiaomi Yi rejected because no Pebble support, in contrast to GoPro Hero 3.
- *Eco Defense Ultrasonic Pest Repeller* which may help in concentrating mice in one region. Link [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014HROTYE). Too unstable and too inefficient if used alone.

---

Is there any mouse traps on the market which are battery operated and give signal when activated etc wifi, bluetooth?

Comment: Reminds me of [Building a better mouse trap, using video surveillance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4PaGvAhV9I). I did wonder about the feasibility of a battery-powered wifi-enabled  Raspberry-pi with a pi-cam to monitor other types of trap.  Some people [make their own wireless monitored mousetraps](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cheap-Wireless-Mousetrap-Alarm-Using-an-ATtiny85/?ALLSTEPS)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Excellent link! It would be great to get some piece of code for Raspberry Pi 2 to get this right away working.

Comment: I can't find if Matthias Wandel makes his code available. There are several sources for similar arrangements - e.g. [This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=45235). I haven't tried any of this myself.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I think this VerminAlert application is interesting. I think a similar product can be made by Raspberry Pi 2 without a camera. It would be great to understand how this VerminAlert can know when there is a mouse and when not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the VerminAlert uses a vibration sensor. It probably works best on spring-loaded mousetraps. The ones I've used jump off the floor when triggered.

Comment: I'd combine the idea of entry-only mouse houses with the idea of gerbil tunnels, and use pipes and 1-way doors to herd them to one central location.  Where you can have comforts like food supply, bartender, little blackjack tables, etc.  which would take the pressure off to empty it immediately, and allow more sophisticated alarms since you only need one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is there any mouse traps on the market which are battery operated and give signal when activated etc wifi, bluetooth?**

Yes. Kinda.

Google is your friend for this kind of thing. A random result:

[image]

Comment: I contacted the support of VerminAlert about the amount of false positives and false negatives. I also asked about the sensitivity of the product. I simply cannot understand how such a device can work without a camera.

Comment: It's a simple matter of the switch being activated when the device is tripped. Why would there be false positives or sensitivity issues?

Comment: See also [Sensorbug BLE](http://www.blehome.com/sensorbug-lp.html) and [BlueRadio](http://www.blueradios.com/hardware_sensors.htm) - looks like a generic bluetooth device with adjustable-sensitivity vibration sensor plus some other sensors.

Comment: It should be easy to make one yourself. So I need a bluetooth chip, a vibration sensor, a board, some simple electronics and a switch. What do you think?

Comment: It should be a fun project.